# Using purrr::map2() with dbplyr

Tags: r, tidyverse, purrr, dbplyr

I'm trying to select lines from one table ("positons") with values for a particular column ("position") that fall within the ranges defined in another ("my_ranges") table, and then to add a grouping tag from the "my_ranges" table.

I can do this using tibbles and a couple `purrr::map2` calls, but the same approach doesn't work with dbplyr database-tibbles. Is this expected behavior, and if so, is there a different approach that I should take to use dbplyr for this kind of task?

Here's my example:

```
library("tidyverse")
set.seed(42)

my_ranges <-
  tibble(
    group_id = c("a", "b", "c", "d"),
    start = c(1, 7, 2, 25),
    end = c(5, 23, 7, 29)
    )

positions <-
  tibble(
    position = as.integer(runif(n = 100, min = 0, max = 30)),
    annotation = stringi::stri_rand_strings(n = 100, length = 10)
  )

# note: this works as I expect and returns a tibble with 106 obs of 3 variables:
result <- map2(.x = my_ranges$start, .y = my_ranges$end,
             .f = function(x, y) {between(positions$position, x, y)}) %>%
  map2(.y = my_ranges$group_id,
              .f = function(x, y){
                positions %>%
                  filter(x) %>%
                  mutate(group_id = y)}
) %>% bind_rows()

# next, make an in-memory db for testing:
con <- DBI::dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), path = ":memory:")

# copy data to db
copy_to(con, my_ranges, "my_ranges", temporary = FALSE)
copy_to(con, positions, "positions", temporary = FALSE)

# get db-backed tibbles:
my_ranges_db <- tbl(con, "my_ranges")
positions_db <- tbl(con, "positions")

# note: this does not work as I expect, and instead returns a tibble with 0 obsevations of 0 variables:
# database range-based query:
db_result <- map2(.x = my_ranges_db$start, .y = my_ranges_db$end,
                  .f = function(x, y) {
                    between(positions_db$position, x, y)
                    }) %>%
  map2(.y = my_ranges_db$group_id,
       .f = function(x, y){
         positions_db %>%
           filter(x) %>%
           mutate(group_id = y)}
  ) %>% bind_rows()
```

Comment: I can do this in straight SQL:
    range_query <- 
    paste0("
        SELECT
          ranges.group_id as group_id,
          positions.position as position,
          positions.annotation as annotation
        FROM
          (SELECT * FROM my_ranges) AS ranges, positions
        WHERE
          positions.position BETWEEN ranges.start AND ranges.end;
           ")
    results <- DBI::dbGetQuery(con, range_query)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`dbplyr` translates `R` into `SQL`. Lists don't exist in `SQL`. `map` creates lists. Thus it's impossible to translate `map` into `SQL`.

Mainly `dplyr` functions and some `base` functions are translated, they're working on `tidyr` functions too as I understood. When using `dbplyr` try to have an `SQL` logic in your approach or it will easily break.

Comment: Thanks! That helps clarify my thinking!

Comment: so is there no way of running something simple like this remotely `iris_db %>% sapply(unique)` (`iris_db %>% map(unique)`)?

Comment: Try something like `map(names(iris_db), ~select_at(iris_db,.x) %>% distinct() %>% collect())`. It will run a separate sql query on each column

Comment: great thanks, I was only able to get it to work though using this type of
approach based on the vignette example [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dbplyr/vignettes/dbplyr.html): `map(dbListFields(con, "flights"), ~select_at(flights_db,.x) %>% distinct() %>% collect())` I had to replace
`names(flights_db)` with `dbListFields(con, "flights")`. Is there a way to use
`names` command on a db dataset to print column names? Its a lot more intuitive than typing `dbListFields`

Comment: Oh yes sorry. I think `colnames() ` would work too.

Answer (score 6):

As long as each iteration creates a table of the same dimensions, then there may be a neat way of pushing the entire operation to the database.  The idea is to use both `map()` and `reduce()` from `purrr`.  Each `tbl_sql()` operation is lazy, so we can iterate through them without worrying of sending a bunch of queries, and then we can use `union()` which will basically append the resulting SQL from each iteration to the next using the `UNION` clause from the given database.  Here's an example:

```
library(dbplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
library(purrr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
library(DBI, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
library(rlang, warn.conflicts = FALSE)

con <- DBI::dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), path = ":dbname:")

db_mtcars <- copy_to(con, mtcars)

cyls <- c(4, 6, 8)

all <- cyls %>%
  map(~{
    db_mtcars %>%
      filter(cyl == .x) %>%
      summarise(mpg = mean(mpg, na.rm = TRUE)
      )
  }) %>%
  reduce(function(x, y) union(x, y)) 

all
#> # Source:   lazy query [?? x 1]
#> # Database: sqlite 3.22.0 []
#>     mpg
#>   <dbl>
#> 1  15.1
#> 2  19.7
#> 3  26.7

show_query(all)
#> <SQL>
#> SELECT AVG(`mpg`) AS `mpg`
#> FROM (SELECT *
#> FROM (SELECT *
#> FROM `mtcars`)
#> WHERE (`cyl` = 4.0))
#> UNION
#> SELECT AVG(`mpg`) AS `mpg`
#> FROM (SELECT *
#> FROM (SELECT *
#> FROM `mtcars`)
#> WHERE (`cyl` = 6.0))
#> UNION
#> SELECT AVG(`mpg`) AS `mpg`
#> FROM (SELECT *
#> FROM (SELECT *
#> FROM `mtcars`)
#> WHERE (`cyl` = 8.0))

dbDisconnect(con)
```

Comment: High quality answer right here, does what you'd like it to do!